# Monotouch binding syntax for blocks

Tags: c#, binding, xamarin.ios, objective-c-blocks

Good day,

I am trying to add a binding for this in Monotouch:

```
- (void)capturePhotoAsImageProcessedUpToFilter:(GPUImageOutput<GPUImageInput> *)finalFilterInChain withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *processedImage, NSError *error))block;
```

I have come this far:

```
[BaseType (typeof(GPUImageVideoCamera))]
interface GPUImageStillCamera{
    delegate void [**What should i put here?**](NSData processedJpeg, NSError error);

    [Export ("capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:")]
    void CapturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter(GPUImageOutput finalFilterInChain);
}
```

I have read the documentation in which the author puts an NSSetEnumerator and i cant wrap my head around where he/she got it from.

Please help me figure this out.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use this:

```
  delegate void CaptureCallback (UIImage processedImage, NSError);

  [BaseType (typeof (GPUImageVideoCamera))]
  interface GPUImageStillCamera {
       [Export ("capturePhotoAsJPEGProcessedUpToFilter:withCompletionHandler:")]
       void CapturePhotoAsJpeg (GPUImageoutput finalFilter, 
                                CaptureCallback completionCallback);
  }
```